# macos mojave lock screen timeout

Tags: keyboard, sleep-wake

I use my MBP in clamshell mode because the keyboard has stuck keys and the display is cracked.

I wake my mac by clicking the mouse or hitting a key on the usb keyboard.

My monitor takes ages to initialise the HDMI and turn on, and then sometimes it is set to the wrong input. By this stage, the mac has often gone back to sleep because nobody has logged on.

How do I change the timeout for the lock screen so that it waits a bit longer - say 1 minute - for someone to log on before going back to sleep mode?

Comment: You can login before the screen wakes. My HTPC Mac attached to a regular consumer TV has similar behaviour. I've just got used to typing blind before the TV wakes up properly.

Comment: doesn't always work. for some reason the mac is slow to bother getting the focus to the login box. I find that when typing in my password its missed the first two or three letters a lot - even when the screen has woken - even after a full format-reinstall.